# How to pass an array from a child component to another child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, react-props

As you can see I have three components, first is Header in which I want to get arr

then second component is CardBox  in which I have created an arr

I am new so as far I know that I have tried

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Header</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const CardBox = () => {
  const arr = ["A", "B", "C"]
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>CardBox</Text>
      <Text>arr in CardBox{arr}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const App = ({arr}) => {
  return (
    <View>
    <Text>arr in Home {arr}</Text>
      <View>
        <Header />
      </View>
      <View>
        <CardBox arr={arr}/>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating Array in your parent component and pass that array as props to your child component e.g.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Header = (props) => {
  const { arr } = props;

  //you can use use selector hook to get the arr from you redux store like this.
  //change your reducer name.
  const arrFromRedux = useSelector((state) => state.reducerName.arr);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Header</Text>
      <Text>arr in Header{arr}</Text>
      <Text>arr from redux in Header{arrFromRedux}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const CardBox = (props) => {
  const { arr } = props;
  //you can use use selector hook to get the arr from you redux store like this.
  //change your reducer name.
  const arrFromRedux = useSelector((state) => state.reducerName.arr);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>CardBox</Text>
      <Text>arr in CardBox{arr}</Text>
      <Text>arr from redux in Header{arrFromRedux}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const arr = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>arr in Home {arr}</Text>
      <View>
        <Header arr={arr} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <CardBox arr={arr} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I hope you got your answer.

Comment: Yeah but in actual example I have created an array in Cardbox and I am using redux to get all states in it, so how can I get same array in parent App component

Comment: is there any specific reason to create an array in child component ?

Comment: coz I am storing data in arr present CardBox using Redux

Comment: want to pass that arr in Header and both Header and CardBox are in App

Comment: So, you can get the REDUX state in your parent component using useSelector() and pass as props or you get the same state in you child component.

Comment: @SaqlainQureshi I have updated the answer using redux state. I hope you got the answer now.

Comment: tried just using const arr= useSelector(state => state.cart.cart); not getting same arr in Parent

Comment: Please share card reducer so I can look is available what you are trying to access.

Comment: where can I share my exact full code with you?, this is my second question on stackoverflow so don't know how to share multiple files

Comment: Thanks...using useSelector directly in Header worked...you saved my day